# JSF, Primefaces: when I quickly click a button on a menu, rendering of a UI is not correct. How to find a cause?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, rendering, facelets

I have a project with a standard template (header-menu-content). When I quickly click button several times, my UI doesn't render correctly. (The header just remains and it is on a center of the page). But at the same time, no one button on the header does not work. Nothing works. `<ui:debug>` at this time does not work as well. I can solve this problem after updating a page in a browser. It seems like elements haven't been downloaded. 
What should I do? How can I find the solution? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: First thing you can do to help us help you is provide a [mcve].

Comment: Solution: add a 'shim' over the page when it is loading and remove it after loading finished. BlockUI is one of these PrimeFaces components that might help in this regard. And please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging on not using tags in titles...

Comment: @Selaron
I have been trying to find the solution and I have encountered to the next exception:
FaceletViewDe E Error Rendering View [someView.xhtml] *java.lang.NullPointerException at org.primefaces.component.menubar.MenubarRenderer.encodeSubmenuIcon.*